# What binaries- thread-safe/non-thread-safe, to use with PHP/WAMP?

Tags: php, windows, dll, thread-safety, wamp

I'm trying to get remote debugging set up on a Windows 7, WAMP server 2.2, PHP, Komodo IDE platform. I need to select a Komodo debugger DLL from the following list:

- nts-v6-x86
- nts-vc9-x86
- ts-v6-x86
- ts-v9-x86

Have no idea which type of binary to choose in this situation. Can someone clue me in?

Comment: Hint, most use the non-thread-safe build of PHP, so much so, that you'd probably know if you were using the thread-safe version.

Answer (score 2):

Wamp 2.2 has been built with VC9. That means that to use PHP's mod_php with Apache 2.2, you need the thread safe version of PHP.

For Fastcgi (with mod_fastcgi) or CLI usage, you can and should use the non thread safe (NTS) version.

Answer (score 1):

PHP binaries for Windows are distributed in version that are non-thread safe (nts) or thread safe (ts) and built against VC9 or VC6:

- http://windows.php.net/download/

You should select the debugger that matches the PHP distribution you have installed.